# Using enum values with J/Link

Tags: java

How can I pass enum values to a function when using J/Link?  What is the correct syntax for typing an enum value?

For example, call [`normalize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html#normalize%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.text.Normalizer.Form%29) using `NFC` from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.Form.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Enumeration value names are accessible using `LoadJavaClass` to load the enum class.  However, this particular case is complicated by the fact that the enum class `Form` is an inner member of the class `Normalizer`.  To load it, we must reference `Form` by its so-called [binary name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1):

```
LoadJavaClass["java.text.Normalizer$Form"];
```

Now we can reference the enum values directly in a call to `Normalizer.normalize()`:

```
LoadJavaClass["java.text.Normalizer"];

Normalizer`normalize[
  MakeJavaObject@FromCharacterCode[{65, 769}],
  Normalizer$Form`NFC] // ToCharacterCode

(* {193} *)
```